# Xcode 7 UI tests via page object pattern

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

Does anyone know if it is possible to start UI tests form the particular place in application? For example, I want to test if I can open the order form from client details. To get to this point I have go from clients table view to client details. Is there something like page-object-pattern in new UI tests Xcode 7?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to start from a particular point in the application, best thing you can do is create helper methods to get you to that point in your test and then call it during your test.

```
func clientDetails() {
    // code to get to this point here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always helpful to use page object patterns in XCode while doing the UITests since most of our tests need to be started at some point which is not the launching point of the app.

Create  Page Objects for different pages which will have the references to the elements in that page and all the helper functions to reach to that page in will go into the page objects. For Example, if you have a login page and a user profile page which comes after login page your page objects should be in the following way. Make sure you pass the testcase to the page object. It wouldn't work otherwise

```
class LoginPageObect {
 let userNameTextField  = XCUIApplication().textFields["UserName"]
 let passwordTextField = XCUIApplication().textFields["Password"]
 let loginButton = XCUIApplication().buttons["LOG IN"]

  func loginUser(testcase: XCTestCase) {
    testcase.waitForElementToAppear(userNameTextField)
    testcase.waitForElementToAppear(passwordTextField)
    userNameTextField.tap()
    userNameTextField.clearText()
    userNameTextField.typeText("Shahid")

    passwordTextField.tap()
    passwordTextField.clearText()
    passwordTextField.typeText("xxxxx")

    loginButton.tap()

   }
 }

class UserProfilePageObject {
 let userNameCell  =   XCUIApplication().tables.cells.staticTexts["Shahid"]


 func navigateToUserProfile(testcase: XCTestCase) {
   let loginPage = LoginPageObect()
   logingPage.loginUser(testCase)
   testcase.waitForElementToAppear(userNameCell)
   userNameCell.tap()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke a selector on a particular view with the XCode 7 UI testing at the moment.However, you can try Backdoor API in calabash-ios to achieve it.

[Calabash-ios backdoor](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Calabash-iOS-Ruby-API#backdoor)